# Regarding @symbol impact on JSON key

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

Am having a JSON structure as below

```
var myJSON = {
               "userTypes": {
                     "@type": "Array",
                     "type": [
                               "Administrator",
                               "Customer",
                               "Guest"
                              ]
                            }
             }
```

When I try to access `myJSON.userTypes.@type` am getting an error "**SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL**" but if I access like this `myJSON.userTypes.type` then am able to access the array.

So my question is,

1. does the @ symbol really doesn't matter in key even it exist ?
2. What impact does this make ?

Regards,

Navin

Comment: How about accessing with "myJSON.userTypes.type" ? even this is also working, why am just trying to find out the difference?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When accessing a property in a JavaScript object you can do so with dot-notation or square-bracket notation.

If you use dot-notation, then you can only access properties which can be represented as an identifier. An identifier cannot start with an `@` character.

Since the property you are trying to access cannot be represented by an identifier, you are limited to square bracket notation. Such:

```
myJSON.userTypes['@type']
```

Comment: How about accessing with "myJSON.userTypes.type" ? even this is also working, why ?

Comment: Because (a) `type` doesn't include an `@` or other character that stops it being used in dot-notation and (b) The object has a `type` property (the value of which is an array containing three strings) AND a `@type` property (the value of which is a string containing the text "Array").

Answer (score 3):

You need to do this: `myJSON.userTypes["@type"]`. Then you can use the `@` as much as you like. The key is referencing the property via string, as I demonstrated.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that it isn't syntactically valid to start an identifier with "@". To access that key, you'll need to do `myJSON.userTypes['@type']`.